# rolling mean with quantile in R language

Tags: python, r

`roll = df.rolling(window=3, center=False).quantile(0.5)`

I am passing [72,73,74,71,75,72,77,75,72,79,73,72] as a DF

I get min `74` max `77`

this code i did in Python

I want to do this in R

there are many libs in R like `caTools` and many more

`runquantile(data[,2],3,probs = 0.5)`(i tried this)

but no one is working properly

please help me out

**Edit.**

Based on the OP comment, here are data and code. This works with [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas).

```
DF <- c(72, 73, 74, 71, 75, 72, 77, 75, 72, 79, 73, 72)
runquantile(DF, 3, probs = 0.5)
```

Comment: What R code have you tried? How are the R tools that you've tried not "working properly"?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. And the error message?

Comment: Works with me: `runquantile(iris[, 1], 3, probs = 0.5)`. No error. Please check your code and be more clear on not "working properly".

Comment: @RuiBarradas updated

Comment: not working properly means -> getting wrong ans

Comment: Then you must post the expected output, as you can see in my new edit to the question, the code outputs something.

Comment: thanks for your time , but can you tell me , how to get MIN and MAX value after that ! which will as same as i get using python ?

Comment: @RuiBarradas  whenever you get sol. please put it here , still need modification of Ques , tell me , i will do

Comment: To get the values you want use `min` and `max`. Or `range`. Try `out <- runquantile(DF, 3, probs = 0.5);range(out)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hello ,it gives me 40 and 80 , which is not expected !

Answer (score 6):

With almost no exception, anything "rolling" to me suggests the `zoo` package:

```r
zoo::rollapply(DF, k=3, FUN=median) 
#  [1] 73 73 74 72 75 75 75 75 73 73
### this returns length(DF)-2*floor(width/2),
### problem if putting into a data.frame .. if so, then pad it:
zoo::rollapply(DF, 3, FUN=median, fill=NA)
#  [1] NA 73 73 74 72 75 75 75 75 73 73 NA
```

(I'll pad all from here on out.)

Quantiles:

```r
zoo::rollapply(DF, width=3, quantile, probs=0.5, fill=NA)
#     50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50%     
#  NA  73  73  74  72  75  75  75  75  73  73  NA
```

Quantiles with multiple `probs` returns a matrix:

```r
zoo::rollapply(DF, width=3, quantile, probs=c(0.5,0.6), fill=NA)
#       50%  60%
#  [1,]  NA   NA
#  [2,]  73 73.2
#  [3,]  73 73.2
#  [4,]  74 74.2
#  [5,]  72 72.6
#  [6,]  75 75.4
#  [7,]  75 75.4
#  [8,]  75 75.4
#  [9,]  75 75.8
# [10,]  73 74.2
# [11,]  73 74.2
# [12,]  NA   NA
```

Same thing, but we can write a function (anonymous or named) that does whatever-we-need:

```r
zoo::rollapply(DF, width=3, FUN = function(x) quantile(x, probs=c(0.5,0.6)), fill=NA)
```

---

For clarity, your statement *"I get min 74 max 77"* can be misleading. I get the full data:

```python
In [15]: DF = pd.DataFrame({'B': [72,73,74,71,75,72,77,75,72,79,73,72]})

In [16]: DF.rolling(window=3, center=False).quantile(0.5)
Out[16]: 
       B
0    NaN
1    NaN
2   73.0
3   73.0
4   74.0
5   72.0
6   75.0
7   75.0
8   75.0
9   75.0
10  73.0
11  73.0
```

Since `center=False`, perhaps the call to `zoo::rollapply` above should use `align=`:

```r
zoo::rollapply(DF, width=3, quantile, probs=0.5, fill = NA, align="right")
#         50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 50% 
#  NA  NA  73  73  74  72  75  75  75  75  73  73
```

The `50%` labels are an artifact of using `quantile` and can be safely ignored and/or removed, as in

```r
zoo::rollapply(DF, width=3, quantile, probs=0.5, fill = NA, align="right", names=FALSE)
#  [1] NA NA 73 73 74 72 75 75 75 75 73 73
```

Comment: ```data.table``` has ```frollmean``` as well: ```library(data.table); frollmean(DF,3)```. It also looks like the more general ```frollapply``` is going to be in a couple of releases from now: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3600

Comment: Good point, Cole. The inclusion of a more-generic `frollapply` makes a lot of sense to me, as `mean` is not the majority rolling-window function I tend to use. Thanks.